# ¿Porque me devuelve mas de una fila mi cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

estoy usando un cursor para traer diferentes datos de dos tablas las cuales son dependientes de una tabla madre pero se desglosa en dos, no lo puedo traer con select debido a que habra inconsistencia en los datos y devolveria vacia la consulta, por ende el cursor.

```
    DECLARE 
   TYPE tRecepciones IS REF CURSOR;
   cRecepciones tRecepciones;

   vNum_OC    NUMBER;
   vNum_FA    NUMBER;
   vRut       VARCHAR2(15);
   vProveedor VARCHAR2(200);
   vEMPRESA   VARCHAR2(15);
   vTIENDA    VARCHAR2(15);
   vDate      DATE;
   

BEGIN 
   OPEN cRecepciones FOR 'SELECT DISTINCT NUMERO_OC, NUM_PACKING_SLIP,FECHA_CREACION
                          FROM   XXX_PO_XXX
                          WHERE  0 = 0
                          AND FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE(''01-09-2021'',''DD-MM-YYYY'') AND TO_DATE(''02-09-2021'',''DD-MM-YYYY'')' ;
                          
                        
   LOOP
      FETCH cRecepciones INTO vNum_OC, vNum_FA,vDate; --> fetch pasa los valores de la instancia a las variables.

         BEGIN 
            SELECT DISTINCT DECODE(EMPRESA, 2, 'X1', 3, 'X2', 'X3'), TIENDA, RUT , PROVEEDOR
            INTO   vEMPRESA, vTIENDA , vRut, vProveedor
            FROM   XXX_OC_XXX_V9
            WHERE  0 = 0
            AND    NUMERO_OC = vNum_OC;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('vEMPRESA: ' ||vEMPRESA ||' - '||' vTIENDA: '||  vTIENDA ||' - '|| ' vRut: ' || vRut || ' - ' || 'vProveedor: ' || vProveedor ||' - '|| 'vNum_OC : ' || vNum_OC ||' - '|| 'vNum_FA : '||vNum_FA || ' - '|| 'vdate: '||vdate);
           
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               BEGIN
                  SELECT DISTINCT DECODE(EMPRESA, 2, 'X1', 3, 'X2', 'X3'), TIENDA, RUT, PROVEEDOR
                  INTO   vEMPRESA, vTIENDA , vRut, vProveedor
                  FROM   XXX_AR_XXX_XJ_V9
                  WHERE  NUMERO_FACTURA = vNum_FA;
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('vEMPRESA: ' ||vEMPRESA ||' - '||' vTIENDA: '||  vTIENDA ||' - '|| ' vRut: ' || vRut || ' - ' || 'vProveedor: ' || vProveedor ||' - '|| 'vNum_OC : ' || vNum_OC ||' - '|| 'vNum_FA : '||vNum_FA || ' - '|| 'vdate: '||vdate);
                 
               EXCEPTION
                  WHEN OTHERS THEN
                     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error 01: ' || SQLERRM);
               END;
         END; 

      EXIT WHEN cRecepciones%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
CLOSE cRecepciones;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error 02: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

En contexto un vNum_oc puede tener varias vNum_FA pero no el mismo repetido.

Comment: puedes poner las relaciones entre tablas y explicar mejor que es lo que quieres?

Comment: Si, de la tabla (padre por asi decirlo) XXX_PO_XXX Sale un Vnum_OC que puede ser nacional para la tabla XXX_OC_XXX_V9 o internacional de la tabla XXX_AR_XXX_XJ_V9. Ambas tienen su facturas , y el problema es que me trae duplicado los datos de las tablas "hijas".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estás complicando mucho para hacer una consulta más o menos sencilla.

Si lo he hecho bien (Al no tener las tablas no he podido probarla) ésto se podría hacer con una consulta como la que te adjunto.

```sql
SELECT DECODE(T1.EMPRESA, 2, 'X1', 3, 'X2', 'X3') CAMPO1, T1.TIENDA, T1.RUT , T1.PROVEEDOR
FROM XXX_OC_XXX_V9 T1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NUMERO_OC 
              FROM XXX_P0_XXX  T2
              WHERE 
                T2.NUMERO_OC = T1.NUMERO_OC
                AND  FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-09-2021','DD-MM-YYYY') 
                                        AND TO_DATE('02-09-2021','DD-MM-YYYY') 
                )
UNION
SELECT DECODE(T3.EMPRESA, 2, 'X1', 3, 'X2', 'X3')CAMPO1, TIENDA, RUT, PROVEEDOR                 
FROM   XXX_AR_XXX_XJ_V9 T3                          
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NUMERO_FACTURA 
              FROM   XXX_AR_XXX_XJ_V9 T4
              WHERE T4.NUMERO_FACTURA = T3.NUM_PACKING_SLIP
)
```

Básicamente he unido las dos consultas con un UNION y la referencia a un cursor que sólo la usabas para discriminar valores por un exists.

En cualquier caso, la respuesta de por qué te está dando varias filas es porque o existen varias filas con el mismo NUMERO_OC en la primera consulta o existen varias con el mismo NUMERO_FACTURA en la segunda.

Fíjate si se hay repetidos o si se aceptan nulos en esos campos. Obviamente, si devuelve más de una fila nunca podrás meter esos valores en variables mediante INTO.

Comment: Concuerdo 100% contigo, hize casi la misma consulta que tu de echo, pero mi SENIOR, quiere que haga scripts para todo y no le gustan las consultas basicas, de todas maneras muchas gracias!